# get utf8 string from PHP page in C# windows application

Tags: c#, php, mysql, sockets, utf-8

I have a **Windows application** that write in C`#` and have a network listener and a `PHP` page that get a string from `mysql` database and send that string via a socket to windows application with this code:

```
$remote_ip='192.168.5.133';//this is the ip of computer that run windows app
ini_set('display_errors',off);
$sh=fsockopen($remote_ip,6000,$en,$en,1);
ini_set('display_errors',on);

fputs($sh,$Text_To_Send_Windows_Application);

$test_keycard=fread($sh,2);
fclose($sh);
```

When I receive the string in windows application, there is something like :

> ¨ÛØ³Øª Ù ÛÚ© Ø§Ø³ÙÙØ¯ ÙØ²Ø§Ø± Ù Ø³ÛØµØ¯ Ù ÙÙØ¯ Ù Ù¾ÙØ¬

I try to convert this code to utf8 format in C# whit this code

```
string plainText = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(UTF8encodes);
```

But it not return original string.

Could anyone tell me how I get original string that send from my `PHP` page?

Comment: You have a webpage with invalid html characters (see : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) So use WebUtility from Net Library : System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode() or System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode()

Comment: WebUtility.HtmlDecode return exactly the input string...about invalid html characters i set it to utf8...do you mean it must be somethings else?

Comment: Yes.  utf8 just converts ASCII character 0-255 to byte array with no conversion. WebUtility does the conversion show on webpage link I provided.

Comment: then i must convert string in win app yeah?

Comment: If the win app is receiving html then yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are expecting Arabic?  Including `ست` etc?  You have Mojibake.  See [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) for more discussion.

Do not use any encoding/decoding functions, it only makes things worse.

You need something like this in the connection:

```
id=my_user;password=my_password;database=some_db123;charset=utf8;
```

(or `utf8mb4`)

If it turns out that you have "double encoding", see [*this*](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,422677,422972)