# How to post an UTF-8 encoded request to a PHP server with TIdHTTP?

Tags: php, delphi, arabic

When I send a string to a PHP page it works fine.

The problem is when I use Arabic language like "محمد", I get a result like "؟؟؟؟". Here is my Delphi code:

```
var
  s: string;
  server: TIdHttp;
begin
  s := 'محمد';
  server := TIdHttp.Create;
  server.Post('http://mywebsite.com/insert_studint.php?name1=' + s);
  server.Free;
end;
```

My PHP code:

```php
<?php
    $name1=$_post['name1'];
    echo $name1;
?>
```

How can I encode my request to UTF-8 to get a proper result on my PHP server?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44214787/get-utf8-string-from-php-page-in-c-sharp-windows-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how URL string query parameters are handled by the [**TIdHTTP**](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/TIdHTTP.html) class. The first parameter of the [**Post**](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/!!OVERLOADED_Post_TIdCustomHTTP.html) method is just the target URL. The URL string query parameters need to be passed as the second parameter of this method as a stream or a string list collection. You need to specify the request encoding in your code as well and the rest will handle the class internally. Try this instead:

```
var
  Server: TIdHTTP;
  Params: TStrings;
begin
  Server := TIdHTTP.Create;
  try
    { setup the request charset }
    Server.Request.Charset := 'utf-8';
    { create the name=value parameter collection }
    Params := TStringList.Create;
    try
      { add the name1 parameter (concatenated with its value) }
      Params.Add('name1=محمد');
      { do the request }
      Server.Post('http://mywebsite.com/insert_studint.php', Params);
    finally
      Params.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Server.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: also he most probable needs HTTP GET not HTTP POST

Comment: @Arioch, the [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) variable from their code doesn't seem to say so.

Comment: thanks about your answer . but now i have other problem
when i try your code there is no data sented to my php.

Comment: Which version of Delphi do you use?

Comment: i use berlin -Victoria

Comment: That should be fine. You've accepted the answer, so did you get this to work? The code posted here should be working (I was using similar for posting with no problems).

Comment: @victoria, thats a good code.but i thing me problem in php code?